# Hypothesis Testing for $\beta_1$ and $\hat{\mu}_{y_h}$

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, linear-model

Experience with a certain type of plastic indicates that a relation exists between the hardness (in Brinell units) of items molded from the plastic ($Y$) and the elapsed time (in hours) since termination of the molding process ($X$). It is proposed to study the relation between $X$ and $Y$ by means of regression analysis. Assume that the simple linear regression model is appropriate for this data.

The plastic manufacturer has stated that the mean hardness should increase by 2 Brinell units per hour. Conduct a two-sided test to decide whether this standard is being satisfied. State the null and alternative hypotheses, compute the test
statistic and p-value of the test.

**Answer**: The problem is easy enough to solve, but my confusion is the phrase "the mean hardness should increase by 2 Brinell units per hour". Am I suppose to be testing $H_0:\beta_1 = 2$ vs $H_a: \beta_1 \neq 2$ or $H_0: \hat{\mu}_{y_h} = 2$ vs $H_a: \hat{\mu}_{y_h} \neq 2$.

Answer (score 2):

**You are supposed to test $\boldsymbol{H_{0}: \beta_1 =2}$ versus $\boldsymbol{H_{a}: \beta_1 \ne 2}$.**

The phrase "the mean hardness should increase by 2 Brinell units per hour" is a *rate* expressed in $\frac{\text{Brinell units}}{\text{hour}}$. Neither $X$ nor $Y$ has those units (i.e., $X$ has "hours" and $Y$ has "Brinell units"). So the value $2$ can also be interpreted "For a $1$-hour increase in $X$, the mean value of $Y$ increases by $2$ Brinell units."

Left **unstated** (but maybe implied?) in the plain text of your question (and possibly the problem you are trying to solve), is what you are trying to *infer*. If you reject $H_0$, then you found evidence for $H_a$ (i.e. the change in $Y$ for a $1$-hour increase in $X$ is something *other* than 2). If you are hope to provide that $\beta_a$ is equivalent to 2, however, you need a different null hypothesis and test.